# Wordpress': wp_enqueue_script within shortcode function?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin that (amongst other things) renders a javascript podcast player in a post via a shortcode. What I did was to write the shortcode function in my plugin file to return the script tags as needed by the player – see below.

This worked quite well but my plugin was rejected by the review team with the comment that I should use the built-in Wordpress functions to enqueue scripts. But whatever I try, I don't manage to get a `wp_enqueue_script` working inside of my shortcode function. I also have tried pre-registering it – but either way, the javascript doesn't get loaded.

Does anybody know a solution for what I'm trying to achieve?

**Update**: Here's the piece of code, I'm struggeling with:

```
function podigee_player( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
      array(
          'url' => '',
      ),
      $atts
    );
    return '<script class="podigee-podcast-player" src="https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js" data-configuration="' . $atts['url'] . '/embed?context=external"></script>';
}
add_shortcode( 'podigee-player', 'podigee_player' );`
```

Comment: Hi Jürgen, could you update your question with an example code of what you are currently doing so that we may try and help correct your code :)

Comment: Definitely! Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 1):

Okay cool, so I see what you're trying to achieve, and I also see why Wordpress would've blocked this.

An accepted way of enqueuing scripts is as below.

You need to state the script you wish to enqueue, and tell Wordpress where it needs to happen. In this instance, the script shall be added in the head, along with other default scripts.

The number I stated at the end is a version number, should you ever need to update it, which is doubtful since the script is external.

```
function podigee_external_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'podigee-podcast-player', 'https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js', '20181023' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'podigee_external_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this won't work (I've already tried). The script needs to render the player at the position in the post – so including it in the header doesn't work. Also: I have no idea how to add the attributes needed to load the right file into the player.

My plan B is: I'll try to convince the Wordpress review team that including the script in the post is the only way this will work. They seem to have an open ear for that. I just don't see an alternative ...

Comment: And adding to the footer? wp_footer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP, but Scott's answer didn't work for me, either.

My solution was, rather than calling:

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'podigee_external_scripts' ); // Not working.`

I just call my function directly:

`podigee_external_scripts(); // Your function that calls wp_enqueue_script(...)`